# Можно ли обработать форму используя функцию php?

Tags: php, html, функции, form

Можно ли как то засунуть обработку формы в функцию ?
Вот форма form.php:

```
 <form method="post" action="">

   
Операция: <input type="text" name="operation" ><br><br>
Доход: <input type="number" name="income" step=".01"><br><br>
Расход: <input type="number" name="expense" step=".01"><br><br>



<input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
</form>
```

И есть файл с функциями func.php:

```
    <?
include("bd.php");

function add_finance ($operation, $income, $expense) {
    if (!empty($_POST["operation"]) && !empty($_POST["income"]) && !empty($_POST["expense"])) 
{
$operation = $_POST["operation"]; 
$income = $_POST["income"]; 
$expense = $_POST["expense"]; 

$result = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO finance SET operation="'.$operation.'", income="'.$income.'" , expense="'.$expense.'"'); 
header("Location:settings.php");
}
else{
echo "Проверьте заполнение полей";}

    
}
?>
```

У меня ничего не работает, подскажите, как можно это реализовать

Comment: чтобы функция запускалась, ее надо вызывать, а не просто добавить код. Также несколько странным выглядит наличие параметров в функции. При условии что сами данные из post вы получаете внутри функции. Обычно кнопку сабмит именуют, а далее в коде проверяют, если в пост есть кнопка, то запускают остальной код.

Comment: Можете показать как это сделать?

Comment: 1. Убедитесь, что запрос и правда пойдёт на func.php, для этого action=“/path/to/func.php” 2. Избавьтесь от функции add_finance, просто вынесите ее тело в файл func.php. Возможно после этих манипуляций скрипт отработает.

Comment: @teran проверка submit - прошлый век. Session + nonce

Comment: @SanyaH вопрос был о простейшем методе проверки типа запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы использовать функцию, необходимо ее вызвать.

Попробуйте так:

```
<?
include("bd.php");

function add_finance ($operation, $income, $expense)
{
$result = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO finance SET operation="'.$operation.'", income="'.$income.'" , expense="'.$expense.'"');
header("Location:settings.php");
}

if (!empty($_POST["operation"]) && !empty($_POST["income"]) && 
!empty($_POST["expense"]))
{
    add_finance ($_POST["operation"], $_POST["income"], $_POST["expense"]);
} else {
echo "Проверьте заполнение полей";}

?>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Спасибо, учту на будущее